# Node.js - create dynamic json object and write to .json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am new to JS ecosystem and a requirement is to create a json object dynamically at run time and to write it to .

```
{
  "prerequisite": [
    {
      "url1": "",
      "step1": {},
      "step2": {}
    }
  ],
  "PF": [
    {},
    {}
  ]
}
```

I tried using new Object() but not sure how to build this complex one (to my extent its complex ).

For writing it to file i understand using FS we can achieve it.

Need support on building this json object at run time

Comment: what's *dynamic* about it? you want help building that object, what does the "source data" look like?

Comment: For example assume that there is a text file from where I am getting the value like url: https://google.com step1:{name:sample} step2:{age:2}. I will get all the value at run time of a function, with that I need to construct json object

Comment: sure, a text file ... and the format of the text file is ... JSON?

Comment: If you have a text json, you can use JSON.parse() for converting JSON strings into JavaScript objects. Than you can use it like json_obj.step1.name (= sample)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you'd like to do something like this. I'm not sure how you want to make it dynamic, but if you have a json object, you can always add to it like this: json_obj.something = "anything"

And it save (overwrite) every time when it runs. Save this code to a file (like filename.js) and run it. (node filename.js)

Oh and must be stringify the json since the FS "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView

```
const fs = require("fs")
const FILE = "./json_obj.json"

const json_obj = {
  prerequisite: [
    {
      url1: "",
      step1: {},
      step2: {},
    },
  ],
  PF: [{}, {}],
}

fs.writeFile(FILE, JSON.stringify(json_obj), (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err)
    return
  }
})
```